# Multipe Scope not working, Use Microsoft Graph API SDK

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, yammer, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have registered an app in the Azure AD portal and given Microsoft Graph API permissions to fetch user data (user.read.) and yammer feeds.

Note: the app is also registered with the yammer portal.

App auth is working fine if I have used a single scope but it fails in case of multiple scopes.

cases :

Working fine in single scope case
val SCOPES = arrayOf("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")

Not Working in multiple scope case
val SCOPES = arrayOf("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "https://api.yammer.com/user_impersonation")

We are using Graph SDK in Android.

Thanks in Advance.

please suggest a way to achieve the solution.

Comment: Can you describe the error?  Are you using the Java SDK or the Android SDK?  The Java SDK is intended as a replacement for the older Android SDK.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Yammer doesn't officially support AAD tokens and the O365 Developer Platform, so it's best that devs follow the supported authentication flows (https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2) until this is eventually supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set two scopes from different resources, which is not supported.

Because, finally you will get an [Azure AD access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens). However, the aud claim in the token can only represents one resource.

[image]

---

**Conclusion:**

1. You can add more than one scopes from one resource. For example: `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All`, `https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite` and other scopes from Microsoft Graph.
2. If you want to get token for more than one resource, you need to get tokens for them separately.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can add just `user.read.all, mail.readwrite` etc too without prefixing with entire graph URL, just that it needs to be comma separated.